# Error "Unreachable statement" al ejecutar el siguiente programa

Tags: java, java-swing

No entiendo cual es el error en el código. El error me sale al final de todo en **`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`**, ahí es el problema y no entiendo porqué.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class asd
    {public static void main (String args [])
    {int i; 
    i=1;
    double n;
    double s;
    s=0;
    double mayor;
    mayor=0;
    double x;
    while(1<=3){
    do{
        n=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa un numero positivo entero"));
        x=Math.floor(n);
    }while(x!=n && n<0);
    s=s+n;
    if(i==1){
        mayor=n;
    }else{
        if(n>mayor){
            mayor=n;
        }
    }
    i++;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El mayor es.."+mayor);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La suma es..."+s);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes un loop que no tiene condición de terminación `while(1<=3)` por eso te dice que  `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` es inalcanzable. Debe ser `i` en lugar de 1.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas definiendo como condicion de un ciclo while en este caso. Al tener la condicion `1<=3` no estas dejando la posibilidad de cambiarlo, ya que 1  siempre será menor que 3, obteniendo `true` por resultado.

**Solucion**: debes definir al menos un variable dentro de la condicion o en base a algun estado que podria darse dentro del ciclo, puedas utilizar una sentencia break. Recuerda no usar constantes como condiciones de ciclos y si las usas debes plantear la forma de salir de el. Espero haberlo dejado claro.